# if statement...if not this id, try the again later

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have two list of ids, both list have the same amount of items, they have the same ids, they are just not in order, example:

```
List 1 - (194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200)

List 2 - (194, 200, 198, 195, 197, 196, 199)
```

I have an if statement that compairs these ids:

```
if (cells[i].scheduleTaskID == taskid)
```

This works well for the first id because they match (194) but the other ids do not match, is there away I can say if taskid does not match cells[i].scheduleTaskID try task id later??

Here is are additional code:

```
int taskid = reader.GetInt32(0); (gets taskid from database)

List<CellModel> cells
```

and this is CellModel:

```
public class CellModel
    {
        public uint scheduleTaskID { get; set; }
        public string task { get; set; }
        public string baselineDate { get; set; }
        public string scheduledDate { get; set; }
        public string actualDate { get; set; }
        public string finishedDate { get; set; }
        public bool selected { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return scheduleTaskID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps `SortedList` would be a better option here then?

Comment: You can sort the list or nested loops !

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code. What is the purpose. Are you trying to find what items are in List1 that are not in List2? Or what?

Comment: Was this ever answered?

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ over a collection to see if your value matches any of the values contained in a collection like this:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200 }; //populate this from db
List<CellModel> cells; 

if(list1.Any(id => id.Equals(cells[i].scheduleTaskID)))
```

If you have a huge list of id's in the database and you don't want to pull down the whole list to compare, you could also loop the reader.

```
while(reader.Read)
        {
            int taskid = reader.GetInt32(0);
            if (cells[i].scheduleTaskID == taskid)
            { 
                // take action and end reading
                break;
            }                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that both are type `List<int>`; if your sole concern is that; numbers in your list is not in order then you can sort them both by calling the `Sort()` function on list and then can loop through them to check content equality like below

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200 };
        List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 194, 200, 198, 195, 197, 196, 199 };

        list2.Sort();
        list1.Sort();

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list1[i] == list2[i])
            {
                //Your Own processing logic here
            }
        }
```

Though I am bit confused as to, what actually you are trying to compare here?